# How does a software-based context-switch with TSS work?

Tags: x86, operating-system

I would like to know a simple explanation for TSS (Task State Segment) and how it is used to do software-based context-switches.

Comment: Why is it unclear what I am asking? I mean the answer perfectly hits the spot. That was what I was asking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, **the TSS is a historical wart**. Once in a time (a.k.a: early 1980's), people at Intel tought that hardware context-switching, instead of software context-switching, was a great idea. They were greatly wrong. Hardware context-switching has several noticeable disadvantages, and, as it was never implemented appropiately, had miserable performance. No sane OS even implemented it due to all of that, plus the fact that it's even less portable than segmentation. See [the obscure corner of OSDevers](http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching#Hardware_Context_Switching) for details.

Now, with respect to the Task State Segment. If any ever OS implemented hardware context-switching, it's purpose is to represent a "task". It's possible to represent both threads and processes as "tasks", but more often than not, in the few code we have using hardware context-switching, it represents a simple process. The TSS would hold stuff such as the task's general purpose register contents, the control registers (CR0, CR2, CR3, and CR4; there's no CR1), CPU flags and instruction pointer, etc...

However, in the real world, where software performs all context switches, we are left with a 104-byte long structure which is (almost) useless. However, as we're talking about Intel, it was never deprecated/removed, and OSes have to deal with it.

The problem is actually pretty simple. Suppose you're running your typical `foo()` function in your typical user-mode process. Suddenly, you, the user, press the Windows/Meta/Super/however-you-call-it key in order to launch your mail client. As a result, an interrupt request (IRQ) is sent from the keyboard into the interrupt controller (either a 8259A PIC or a IOAPIC). Then, the interrupt controller arranges things in order to trigger a CPU interrupt. The CPU enters into privilege level 0, The registers are pushed, along with the interrupt number, and kernel-mode code is invoked to handle the situation. Wait! Pushing stuff? Where? On the stack, of course! But, where is the stack pointer taken from in order to define a "stack"?

If you happened to use the user-mode stack pointer, bad things *will* happen, and a giant security exploit would be available. What would happen if the stack pointer pointed into an invalid address? It could happen. After all, strictly speaking, the stack pointer is just another general purpose register, and assembly programmers are known to use it that way for hardcoreness' sake.

An attempt to push stuff there would generate a CPU exception, nice! And, as double faults (exceptions that occur while attempting to handle interrupts) would yet again attempt to push over the invalid pointer, the worst nightmare of an operating system becomes true: a triple fault. Have you ever seen your computer suddenly reboot without any prior advice? That is a triple fault (or a power failure). The OS has no change to handle a triple fault, it just reboots everything.

Great, the system has rebooted. But, something worse could have happened. Had an attacker purposefully written the address of a critical kernel variable (!), and put the values that him would like written there in the right order, let the greatest privilege elevation exploit reign as getting superuser privileges becomes easier than ever! GDB, the kernel's configuration (found in `/proc/config.gz`, and the GCC version the kernel was compiled with are more than enough to do this.

Now, back to the TSS, it happens that the aforementioned structure contains the values of the stack pointer and the stack segment register that are loaded upon a interrupt while in privilege level 3 (user-mode). The kernel sets this to point to a safe stack in kernel-land. As a result, there's a "kernel stack" per thread in the system, and a TSS per each logical CPU in the system. Upon thread switching, the kernel just changes these two variables in the right TSS. And no, there can't be a single kernel stack per Logical CPU, because the kernel itself may be preempted (most of the time).

I hope this has led some light on you!