# How to multiple threads share register windows in sparc processor

Tags: multithreading, cpu-registers, processor, sparc

In an intel processor, in loose terms, typically register file, TLB and some excpetion state management are thread-aware.

Is the register windows implementation in sparc processor thread-aware ? How does sparc processor execute multiple threads concurrently ?

Answer (score 1):

Each sparc hardware thread (strand) has its own private set of registers. So all the threads in a core can execute concurrently with no worries about sharing of the registers. Basically, each h/w thread is a complete cpu, though there is sharing of some processing, cache, and TLB resources within a core. Details are dependent on each individual processor model.

Comment: Does each strand have a set of register windows for itself ? Or are the register windows shared between threads ? Arch manuals say a max of 8 register windows may be implemented. Does this mean 1 register window per thread (and this doesnt sound right) ?

Comment: As I said, each sparc hardware thread (strand) has its own private set of registers. Register windows are not shared among threads. When the manual says a max of 8 register windows may be implemented, that means per thread.

Comment: Can you please add some source for this information ? The reason I ask is because if each thread has its own set of register windows, thats a whole lot of registers ! If there are 8 threads per CPU, this means there are 64 register windows; this in turn means a total of 64*24 registers = 1536 registers + globals.

Comment: Yes, that is a lot of registers, and that is one of the reasons why the sparc chip has billions of transistors. I'd recommend reading chapter 15 "Chip Level  Multithreading" in any of the OSA documents from the last 10 years or so. Google for "Oracle SPARC Processor Documentation" if you don't have one handy.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem. Threads are an OS concept; as such, the OS manages threads. AFAIK SPARC does not provide any specific HW support for threads. But I think the WIM register comes in handy. In any case, you could look at RTEMS' source code to see how a real OS manages threads on SPARC.

These are my guesses. If we were known to have 2 threads and the HW had 8 register windows, we could pre-allocate 4 windows for each thread. Now, the OS needs to be notified when a register window of the other thread is going to be used, as a result of a procedure call, i.e. save instruction.

The WIM register holds a mask of invalid register windows. Whenever an invalid register window is going to be used, while executing the save instruction, an exception is raised. That ia the OS executes, which can push a previous register window to memory, and allocate that one for the thread. All the OS needs to do is to set the WIM register before it allocates the processor to a thread.

Also the OS could save the complete register file to memory when it changes the running thread. This would increase the memory traffic. In the end, the OS, which executes in Supervisor mode, can access any register window.

In summary, I think there is no specific HW for threads management (can't remember now whether the SRMMU has anything thread-aware...). However, there are ways to implement a threading model on top of SPARC.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're asking about SMT (one physical core pretending to be / presenting itself as multiple full cores).  In SPARC terminology, apparently a logical core is called a "strand".

"Thread aware" is not the usual terminology: the question is whether a hardware resources is replicated for each strand, statically partitioned (each thread gets 1/2 or 1/8th), or dynamically / competitively shared.  (e.g. L1 cache is typically up for grabs, so one thread doing a lot of memory-intensive work can cause more cache misses for other threads on the same core by evicting their lines).

**Each logical thread, aka strand, has its own full set of register windows**, or at least software sees it that way.  However it's implemented internally, a hardware thread (strand) acts like a full core.

I think the hardware has some discretion over when to trap on running out of room internally and needing to spill windows to memory, so an implementation that doesn't fully replicate the space for all windows of all register files might spill less often when fewer strands are running on the same physical core.  (I don't know much about SPARC, I forget if those traps are supposed to be deterministic).

From [UltraSPARC T1<sup>TM</sup> Supplement to the UltraSPARC Architecture 2005](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/opensparc/t1-09-ust1-uasuppl-draft-hp-ext-1537737.html), **Figure 1-3 SPARC Core Block Diagram** indicates that the hardware in that old CPU really did replicate the full register files.

[image: UltraSparc manual Figure 1-3]

On a CPU with out-of-order exec + register renaming for a small set of architectural registers (like x86), the architectural registers for a single logical core only take up some of the total register file.

But SPARC's register windows take a lot of space.  The CPU only need random access to the registers that are currently live, though, so SRAM arrays to store non-visible windows shouldn't be too bad.  I'd guess that the physical hardware would copy a block of registers to a save area instead of having a huge indexable register file for all the windows.

---

If you're asking about context switches on one logical core:

No, x86 registers aren't thread-aware.  Software saves / restores registers during a context switch.  Nobody uses the x86 TSS hardware task-switching because it's slow and inconvenient. ([How does a software-based context-switch with TSS work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828347/how-does-a-software-based-context-switch-with-tss-work)).

Writing the x86 `CR4` control register with a new page-table base address does invalidate the TLB entries for that logical core.  (Or with process-context-ID, TLB entries are tagged.)

@Juanrgar's answer points out that an OS could maybe play tricks with register windows to have the contexts for 2 software threads in the physical registers of a logical core.  I have no idea if any OSes do this; it would make the context-switch bookkeeping more complicated if you had to decide which half of the register windows to use when switching to a new thread.